# Does the DocuSign API support google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, docusignapi

I have a funnel that hops over to DocuSign mid-stream and then back to my site.  Analytics is correctly reporting this as an "exit", but I want the DocuSign step to be included in my funnel.

Does DocuSign support cross domain tracking with Google Analytics?

**MORE INFO**: We are using DocuSign's API to generate the envelope.  The user is then redirected to DocuSign's web site to do the actual signing.  When finished, DocuSign is configured to navigate the user back to our site to finish the sign-up process.

Comment: What do you mean by "hops over to DocuSign?" Using the API? Powerforms? Something else? Your question needs to be more specific. Include examples. What's working, what's not working?

Answer (score 3):

I have very little experience with DocuSign.  It might be possible to do this using a [tracking gif](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview?hl=en#gifRequestClassification).   It may be possible to embed it in your envelope.

> A GIF request is sent to the Analytics servers in the following cases
>   and classified according to the table below. In each of these cases,
>   the GIF request is identified by type in the utmt parameter. In
>   addition, the type of the request also determines which data is sent
>   to the Analytics servers. For example, transaction and item data is
>   only sent to the Analytics servers when a purchase is made. User,
>   page, and system information is only sent when an event is recorded or
>   when a page loads, and the user-defined value is only sent when the
>   _setVar method is called.

Example:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4&utmn=769876874&utmhn=example.com&utmcs=ISO-8859-1&utmsr=1280x1024&utmsc=32-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=9.0%20%20r115&utmcn=1&utmdt=GATC012%20setting%20variables&utmhid=2059107202&utmr=0&utmp=/auto/GATC012.html?utm_source=www.gatc012.org&utm_campaign=campaign+gatc012&utm_term=keywords+gatc012&utm_content=content+gatc012&utm_medium=medium+gatc012&utmac=UA-30138-1&utmcc=__utma%3D97315849.1774621898.1207701397.1207701397.1207701397.1%3B...
```

Comment: Interesting, let me look into that.

Comment: Let me know how it goes it was just an idea. If it doesn't work I can delete this.